# Using javascript templates in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, tabs

I have a php document in which I add 'chapters' (jquery tabs) in two ways:

1. When a new chapter is created, it will be added to the list, and to the database, using javascript and Ajax. As you see, I already have a tabTemplate which is used for that.

   ```
   li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#tabs-" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ).replace(/#\{chapid\}/g, id) );

   tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
   ```
2. When tabs are initialized from the database, php and mysql will add the chapters to the list:

   ```
   while($chaprow = mysql_fetch_array( $chapters )) 
   {
     echo '<li><a href="#tabs-'.$chaprow['id'].'">'.$chaprow['name'].'</a><a href="#" onclick="deleteChapter('.$chaprow['id'].');return false;">D</a></li>';
   }
   ```

How can I use the template I created in Javascript in the initialization of my database chapters?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for help writing the AJAX call or in doing the database organization?

Comment: I already have the AJAX call, just need to get data out of the database and put the values in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Share templates using [Mustache for PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) and [for JS](http://mustache.github.io/), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Print the data and let JS take care of the template. i.e.:

```
echo '<script>var Tabs.list = '. json_encode($tablist) .'; Tabs.init()</script>';
```